# bigquery export table gcs nodejs no me funciona

Tags: nodejs, google-cloud-platform

he estado realizando los ejemplos para exportar una ***tabla de Bigquery*** a ***cloud Storage*** https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#bigquery-export-table-gcs-nodejs, con ***gcloud***, ***python***, funcionó,  funcionó, pero Node Js no me funciona, me sale el siguiente error:

```
> node test.js
/home/nodejs/test.js.js:26
.extract(storage.bucket(bucketName).file(filename))
 ^
TypeError: bigquery.dataset(...).table(...).extract is not a function
at extractTableToGCS (/home/nodejs/test.js.js:26:6)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/nodejs/test.js.js:50:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:201:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:626:3
```

Es muy sencillo solo reemplazar las variables, pero no me funcionó, agradezco una respuesta.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de las librerías estás utilizando? `npm ls @google-cloud/bigquery` y `npm ls @google-cloud/storage`

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta, estoy utilizando:

"@google-cloud/bigquery": "0.9.6"

Comment: Acabo de actualizar las librerias y ***funcionó***:
    "@google-cloud/bigquery": "^1.0.0"
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^1.5.2"

Agradezco tu ayuda.